# Setup Projects with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

If you setup your document root as C:\xampp\htdocs\ and you create a project folder named "ProjectX" where you include all your project files and folders and subfolders, how are you going to make your project runnable with url "http://localhost/projectx" ? I would like to learn how your config and routes files you included in your projects are changed ?

Comment: Have you download & extract the source of cakephp in your destination folder ?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below link

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/912/Installation

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would not run them as "localhost".
If you link css/js/img absolute to the / root, you will run into problems later on your life server.

it is always best to use virtual hosts and simulate the "real life" on your system:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder `projectx` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

Then copy all the CakePHP files in `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\` (including .htaccess, app\, lib\ and all. Setup the salt, cypher, db files and you should be able to access it through `http://localhost/projectx/`